# Boxing and UnBoxing on Android

Tags: java, android, unboxing

I'm developing an Android application.

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IDBAdapter {

    public enum Table {
        ...
    }
    public int insertItem(Table table, Object item);
    public boolean removeItem(Table table, long rowIndex);
    public Cursor getAllItemsCursor(Table table);
    public Cursor setCursorToItem(Table table, long rowIndex);
    public void getItem(Table table, long rowIndex);
    public boolean updateItem(Table table, long rowIndex, Object item);
}
```

For each table defined on `enum Table`, it will be an object that represents that table.

My problem is about parameter `Object item`. I will have to unbox each item every time I call one of this methods and I don't know if this will be very slow for Android.

Do you know a better solution? I don't want to create a DBAdapter for each table because I should share SQLiteDatabase object between each other.

**UPDATE:**

Here is an example of object that I need to pass to those methods:

```
public class GameDescriptionData {
    public int gameId;
    public char[] language = new char[5];
    public String name;
    public String description;

    public GameDescriptionData() {
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't said what kind of values you're putting into the tables. Unless you're inserting primitive values, there won't be any boxing involved. For example, if `item` is a `String` reference, that doesn't need boxing because it's a reference already.

I suggest you try your ideal design before changing it for the sake of performance concerns. Admittedly I'm not entirely convinced this is a great design to start with, but it's hard to say without knowing more about your application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my question with an example for Object item.

Comment: @VansFannel: Well as that's a class, there won't be any boxing involved.

Comment: You've said: "Admittedly I'm not entirely convinced this is a great design to start with,..."  What do you suggest?

Comment: @VansFannel: I couldn't possibly suggest a design without knowing details about what you're trying to do... and I'm afraid I don't have the time (at least today) to look at any details. Maybe this *is* a good design for you... but I rarely use just `Object` in Java these days...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to impl the distinct care for each expected item.
 Define `DBAdapterStrategyFactory` that will store all the strategies together based on their class type. This way, when calling operations on `Object item` you can pull that strategy from the factory and share most of the `IDBAdapter` code.